# VB.NET devexpress winform panel change with click items

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, panel

I have a winform study that have 2 panel  (Panel1 and Panel2); see pictures.
When I click EngineInputs, I can see Panel1 and panel2 hide, but when I click transmission input I cannot see panel2, only see blank screen.

I want;

Engine Input Click ==> see Panel1 hide Panel2

Transmission input Click ==> see Panel2 hide Panel1

see my codes below

[image]

```
Private Sub inboxItem_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraNavBar.NavBarLinkEventArgs) Handles inboxItem.LinkClicked
    Panel1.Show()
    Panel2.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub outboxItem_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraNavBar.NavBarLinkEventArgs) Handles outboxItem.LinkClicked
    Panel1.Hide()
    Panel2.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Panel1.Hide()
    Panel2.Hide()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: try BringToFront() method on the displaying panel if they added to same control..

Comment: Yeah, `BringToFront()` will definitely help, but just a note: You should not try this with Panels. Use MDI forms - and do yourself a favor and use the DevExpress DocumentManager to handle them.